# Getting Segmentation fault while trying to initialise a 3 dimensional vector dynamically in a loop

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic, 3d, segmentation-fault

I am creating a vector<vector<vector>> called points_in_clusters.
The purpose is to store the lines of a csv file(points) into a 3D vector. The first dimension of the vector is the cluster number and the rest (vector<vector>) is the set of points belonging to the corresponding cluster.
So for example, after reading the file I expect to have a vector like this:

```
vector<vector<vector<string>>> points_in_clusters = 
{
{{"a","b","c"},{"q","w","e"}}, //points which belongs to cluster "0"
{{"f","k","l"} , {"a","b","l"},{"f","b","l"}} //belongs to cluster "1"
};
```

The problem is that I can't do this dynamically and in a loop because I get this error:
Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${command}

Here is the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   
    char fileName[] =  "points.csv";
    int k = 2;
    /*****read_initial_clusters*****/
    vector<vector<vector<string>>> points_in_clusters;

    for(int numCluster = 0 ; numCluster < k ; ++numCluster){
        read_initial_clusters(k , fileName , step , numCluster  ,points_in_clusters);
    }

return 0

}
```

And here is the read_initial_clusters function:

```
void read_initial_clusters(int k , string fileName , int step , int numCluster  , vector<vector<vector<string>>>& points_in_clusters ){
    
    int numCommas = 0;
    
    string line;
    ifstream myfile(fileName,ios::in);

    vector<string> point;
    
    
    if(!myfile.is_open()){
        cout<<"Failed to open"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    
    int start_line = numCluster * step;
    int end_line = start_line + step;
    

    int myShare = 0;
    int line_counter = 0; 

    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
       
        if( myShare <= step)
        {
            if(start_line <= line_counter && line_counter < end_line)
            {
                myShare++;
                stringstream sline(line);
                string word;
                while (getline(sline , word , ','))
                {
                    point.push_back(word);
                    numCommas++;
                }
                
                **points_in_clusters[numCluster].push_back(point);**//------->Source of error
                point.clear();
                line_counter++;

            }
            else
            {
    
                line_counter++;

            }
         
        }
        else
        {
            
            myfile.close();
        }
            

    }//While
    
}
```

The thing is, if I first initialise my points_in_clusters with some mumble jumble (considering the number of first dimension), then the push_back in the "read_initial_clusters function" works properly but if not, I get this seg fault error. On the other hand, the only thing that is definite beforehand is the number of my first dimension which is the cluster number and the rest has to be filled dynamically.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vector is empty, just change this

```
for(int numCluster = 0 ; numCluster < k ; ++numCluster){
    read_initial_clusters(k , fileName , step , numCluster  ,points_in_clusters);
}
```

to this

```
for(int numCluster = 0 ; numCluster < k ; ++numCluster){
    points_in_clusters.push_back({});
    read_initial_clusters(k , fileName , step , numCluster  ,points_in_clusters);
}
```

Looks like you are handling the other dimensions correctly, but you also need to `push_back` on the first dimension.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved the problem. But why for a 3d vector I need to do this while for a 2d..I used to do nothing rather than just simply push_back?

Comment: But all I'm doing here is push_back.

Comment: The code in `read_initial_clusters` says `points_in_clusters[numCluster]` my change just makes sure that element exists before you try to access it.

Comment: I see. I meant I didn't need to push_back({}) for a 2D. Just reading the file and push_back the lines one by one.

Comment: Another approach would be `points_in_clusters.resize(k);` before your for loop, no need to `points_in_clusters.push_back({});` in the for loop then. That's actually better since you do know in advance how big the outer dimension is.